# Construir rejillas de forma dinámica

Tags: html5, bootstrap, css3

Estoy construyendo una cola de trabajo por medio de rejillas, actualmente construyo las rejillas de acuerdo a la cantidad de columnas (registros) que itero de acuerdo una consulta que realizo en la DB.

Actualmente itero para construir las columnas, la variable `@col` puede tener valores como 4,5,6,etc.. de manera que las columnas se construirán diatónicamente.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="col-xs-@col" style="padding:0; margin:0;">
      <!-- El contenido que muestro en cada columna  -->         
  </div>
</div>
```

Ejemplo: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi problema es el siguiente: al momento de iterar ocupo todo el ancho del contenedor si el valor es: 12, 8, 6, 4, 2; pero si el valor es: 11, 9, 7, 5, 3, 1 las rejillas no llenarán el contenedor.

Lo que se me ocurre pero no se como hacerlo es: Que el ancho de cada columna sea estático (pueden ser controlado en pixeles), pero necesito agregar n cantidad de columnas, permaneciendo todas con el mismo ancho, quiero poder agregar n cantidad (incluso más de 12 si fuera el caso), desplazarse a lo ancho no sería problema.

Espero se entienda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

podrías usar Medias Queries , para manipular **Bootstrap** .

Aquí hay un ejemplo manipula el modelo de Rejilla de **Bootstrap** con **Media Queries**

https://www.cubicfactory.com/bootstrap-modificando-la-rejilla-los-media-queries-iii/

En este ejemplo se genera una de 5 rejillas.-

Saludos.